# VBA Copy data from the file I select to the next empty row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, copy-paste

I am trying to get data to be copy over to the next empty row. I have data starting in Cell A6. Can you please advise why my Lastrow2 is giving me an error and not copying the data to next empty row?

```
Dim FTO As Variant
Dim OB As Workbook
Dim Lastrow2 As Long

Lastrow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
FTO = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *xls*")

If FTO <> False Then
        Set OB = Application.Workbooks.Open(FTO)
        OB.Sheets(1).Range("E4:BW100").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range("A6" & Lastrow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OB.Close False
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I have tried modifying the lastrow function using the following code. Can I use the piece below to work on the function?

```
Lastrow2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A6").End(xlDown).Row + 1

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

If FTO <> False Then
        Set OB = Application.Workbooks.Open(FTO)
        OB.Sheets(1).Range("E4:BW100").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master").Range("A6" & Lastrow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        OB.Close False
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Values From a Closed Workbook

**The Issue**

The expression `LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(-1).Row` is wrong because of the `-1` and could only work in a *With* statement:

```
Dim FirstRow As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master") 
    FirstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
End With
```

or, if you need the first cell

```
Dim FirstCell As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master") 
    Set FirstCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End With
```

These leading dots tell us that these cells or rows are located in the worksheet `Master` in the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).

**An Improvement**

```
Sub CopyValues()

    ' Define constants.
    ' The Source workbook will be opened using 'Application.GetOpenFilename'.
    Const SRC_WORKSHEET_INDEX As Long = 1
    Const SRC_RANGE As String = "E4:BW100"
    ' The Destination workbook is the workbook containing this code.
    Const DST_WORKSHEET_NAME As String = "Master"
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "A"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Open the Source file (or not).
    Dim SourcePath: SourcePath = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        Title:="Browse for your File & Import", _
        FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *xls*")
    If VarType(SourcePath) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub ' i.e. 'False'
    
    ' Reference the Source range.
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(SourcePath)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(SRC_WORKSHEET_INDEX)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(SRC_RANGE)
    
    ' Reference the Destination range.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Sheets(DST_WORKSHEET_NAME)
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, DST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    
    ' Copy values.
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    
    ' Close the Source file.
    swb.Close False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Would it be possible to copy the "E4:BW100" from sheet 1 and also column "B4:B100, D4:D100" from sheet 2 from the source file?